# Did besiegers ever come up through the latrine?

Tags: siege, castles

About seven minuets into [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZH3JKYHPy40) he explains about the latrine in the castle and how it would be blocked up during a siege to keep people out. Is the historian correct in saying this? I was wondering if this was just a logical precaution, or whether they were adapting to data from previous castles and sieges. I wouldn't imagine that it would be any easier or effective than trying to take a ladder to the battlements, (especially when the latrine over hangs the river) unless they managed to do it without the defenders noticing.

**Are there historic references to people breaking into a castle by coming up through the latrine?**

Comment: [Not reliably sourced legend](https://www.historyhit.com/facts-about-medieval-castles/)  [Same event, still no source](https://www.warhistoryonline.com/war-articles/weird-siege-tactics.html)  Both appear to link to the same castle, so that might be a hint for further research.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Ch%C3%A2teau_Gaillard gives an example.

Comment: @kimchilover: one has to wonder how correct the description is or how wide the chute was. Because the linked Wikipedia article would suggest it wasn't that wide. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garderobe#Toilet

Comment: @Fizz I agree, but the intruder might have carried tools with him to widen the gap at the end of his ascent.  One wonders what the original source of the Gaillard latrine story is.  Wikipedia seems to cite a lot of recent secondary popularizations and no primary sources here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:  Yes.

One example:

> The protruding shaft of masonry that made up the toilet was buttressed from below or might nestle in the junction between a tower and wall. Some waste shafts were short while others reached almost to the ground. In the latter case, that might prove a dangerous design feature if there were a siege of the castle. Indeed, besiegers used just such a latrine shaft in 1203-4 CE to gain entry to Chateau Gaillard on the River Seine in France, built by Richard I (r. 1189-99 CE) at the end of the 12th century CE. After the siege, to ensure no repeat of the trick, a masonry wall was built around the shaft exit.

https://www.worldhistory.org/article/1239/toilets-in-a-medieval-castle/